# developing android applications

Tags: android

hey people.i would like to know how to develop applications for android.
i know nothing about it.and want to start frm the scratch..so tell me what all i need to study/ thanks.

Comment: Seriously, this link will make you a famous Android developer right away -> http://developer.android.com/index.html

Comment: This is way too broad a question to offer anything more than the developer link that @Viktor mentioned.

Comment: You will also probably have to learn some Java before, I’m sure there are a lot of good Java tutorials on Internet.

Comment: Wouldn't it be cool, if there was a website that would search the web for keywords?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've listed a lot of tutorials, links, books, videos in this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2869338/where-to-start-to-learn-android/2869373#2869373

Answer (score 1):

Best resource is the developer.android.com website. Download the SDK and go through the sample code tutorials [here](http://developer.android.com/resources/browser.html?tag=sample). And there is always people on Stackoverflow to help out with any problems. All the Best !

Comment: do i need to learn any new language..or something?